# Python, finding position of a charater in a string

Tags: python

```
    >>> s.index("r")
    >>> s.find("r")
```

The above only finds the first character. For example:

```
    >>>s='hello'
    >>>s.find('l')
```

only outputs 2. What if we want the position of both 'l' and want the output

```
    >>>[2, 3]
```

Comment: Try to check the documentation first before asking. Both [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) accept a second optional argument related to starting position of search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, with `enumerate`, like this

```
>>> [index for index, char in enumerate(s) if char == "l"]
[2, 3]
```

The `enumerate` function will give the current index as well the current item in the iterable. So, in each iteration, you will get the index and the corresponding character in the string. We are checking of the character is `l` and if it is `l`, we include the `index` in the resulting list.

Comment: Thanks fortheye, it works but this has not been covered in my class and i would feel kind of like cheating if i used this. Do you know of any simpler method? also what if the string is not fixed and its a user input?

Answer (score 0):

thefourtheye's  solution is the best but if you want a different method:

```
s = raw_input("Enter a string")
c = raw_input("Enter a char to search")

indexes = []
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == c:
        indexes.append(i)
    i += 1
print "{} appears {} times at the following index/indexes {}".format(c,len(indexes),indexes)
```

Comment: This is very unpythonic. A counter variable is unnecessary in python.

Comment: @IanAuld, what are you talking about, I have already stated thefourteyes's solution is the best, I have provided another way not using enumerate and to show  having different user input  does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is thefourtheye's answer expanded into a normal function:

```
def count_chars(string, char):
    results = []
    for index, value in enumerate(string):
        if value == char:
           results.append(index)
    return results
```

However thefourtheye's answer is the best most pythonic answer. List comprehensions, and comprehensions in general, are a very important part of Python (and one of my favorite parts). I strongly suggest reading up on them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Nothing wrong with being a little ahead of the curve :-).